# Knockout load another AJAX url to combine to model

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js

I have some complex question.
My first JSON url has this properties, ID, Name and Parameter. Then when I call the JSON, I want to go to retrieve another JSON URL based on the ID to get the child ID.

Then I want to output as Child ID, Parent Name and Parent Parameter.

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c3L7gr4w/1/

And here is the model url 1

```
[
{
  "ParemeterValues": "Actual,2011,SYS.LoadCompanies,y,y",
  "ID": "1771cdf7-7a73-49e4-8538-0d0cad965226",     
  "Name": "EXEC.Data.PLandBS.FromFMISMultipleCompanies",   
},
{
  "ParemeterValues": "Actual,2012",
  "ID": "19439ce4-240c-4f2a-98ee-47cb1708b339",
  "Name": "Data.BS.BringForwardOpeningBalances",  
}
 ]
```

and the model url2

```
{
"ID": "1771cdf7-7a73-49e4-8538-0d0cad965226",
"Name": "EXEC.Data.PLandBS.FromFMISMultipleCompanies",
"TM1.ChoreProcessesProcess": 
[
  {
  "Name": "EXEC.Data.PLandBS.FromFMISMultipleCompanies",
  "ID": "dd1acc0b-51ff-4844-b6c4-c67640b326c4",
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Your JS code sample does not look good. Check the brace balancing. Ideally [make a *working* reproduction of your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use the built-in code snippets or jsFiddle, for example. Also please improve your explanation, your question is confusing.

Comment: Ok, for starting, this is a jsFiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/c3L7gr4w/1/

How can I change the ID to dd1acc0b-51ff-4844-b6c4-c67640b326c4 while the other information is the same, when the load updated data click.
   
   var updatedData = [
    {
   "ID": "1771cdf7-7a73-49e4-8538-0d0cad965226",
   "Name": "EXEC.Data.PLandBS.FromFMISMultipleCompanies",
   "TM1.ChoreProcessesProcess": 
    [
   {
   "Name": "EXEC.Data.PLandBS.FromFMISMultipleCompanies",
   "ID": "dd1acc0b-51ff-4844-b6c4-c67640b326c4"
    }
    ]
    }
   ];

Comment: well simon as far my knowledge goes you have to do like this : http://jsfiddle.net/c3l7gr4w/2/

Comment: Hi supercool, nice try but that won't work. The JSON data can't be altered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to adjust your dataMappingOptions.key so that KO can return a different key when you load your child model in on top of your original.

I have a working fiddle here, I think - http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/c3L7gr4w/4/

dataMappingOptions now looks like:

```
var dataMappingOptions = {
    key: function(data) {
        var ChildID = "";
        if (data["TM1.ChoreProcessesProcess"] != undefined)
            ChildID = data["TM1.ChoreProcessesProcess"][0].ID
        return data.ID + ChildID;       
    },
    create: function(options) {
        return new Person(options.data);
    }        
};
```

The problem with this is that when you load your updatedData KO will now use the mapping to destroy your original people and create new ones. However, updatedData is missing the ParemeterValue, so you need to merge this in from your original JSON. This will be OK even when you are using Ajax, because you can save the original JSON in a variable somewhere:

```
loadUpdatedData: function() {
    // You need to merge in paremeterValues from your orig JSON
    updatedData[0].ParemeterValues = data[0].ParemeterValues;
    // Now good to go...
    ko.mapping.fromJS(updatedData, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.people);  
}
```

(I've also done it so that ChildID is appended as an extra property, but you should be able to see from this how to make it replace the original ID in both the People view-model and in the dataMappingOptions.key)